# how to count who has most friends in facebook?

Tags: facebook

Let's assume I have  a Facebook Event.

how to count which attender has the biggest amount of friends attended into this same Event?

Comment: The skillful part would be counting the number of "friends" the person has compared to real life.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have access to a user's social graph (friends list) unless they give you permission, which is generally achieved through an application. If you're simply a FB user or page hosting an event, you don't have access to this information (even if you're a page and they're a fan).

Comment: If I make an app for this, does the app have access to the event's attender info?

Comment: If your app requires authorization, yes.